# UWP - app crash in Release mode, missing dll?

Tags: c#, dll, uwp

I´m develop a C# UWP-App and added a few nuget-packages, also I referenced manually two dll´s. The application works in debug-mode very well in the (x86) Simulator and also on my Remotedevice (Raspi).
 
As soon as I use the release-version or the appx-Package, the functions from the both dll´s are missing/failing.
What I see in the app-directory is a difference in the file structure. In debug-mode all dll´s are in the directory. In release mode only the appname.dll exists.
I tried to add the dll also as "content" with "copy always" without success.
Any idea what I need to do to get a working release-version?

Comment: Have you tried to package it on another device? Did it work before after you added the DLLs?

Comment: @RoyLi-MSFT: Yes. tried it on different devices. Did it works before I added the DLLs. Yes. Can it be, that all neccessary references are included/packed in one new DLL?

Comment: Could you please tell me what's the specific error message you are getting when you say ` the functions from the both dll´s are missing/failing`?

Comment: The app crashes in functions from the DLLs. But this happens only in Release version. Now I found a way to get running the app. The difference between DEBUG and RELEASE  build is the option  "compile with the .net native tool chain". After I unchecked this, my app works in release mode as expected.

Answer (score 2):

After I unchecked the option "compile with the .net native tool chain" for the RELEASE Build, the app is working as expected.